# C++ Static member pointer to function - how to initialize it?

Tags: c++, static, function-pointers

I have a static pointer to function like the following in my class, but I'm not sure how to instantiate it:

```
class Foo{ 
 private:   
    static double (*my_ptr_fun)(double,double);                               
};
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The same way you would initialize every other static member object in C++03:

```
class Foo{ 
 private:   
    static double (*my_ptr_fun)(double,double);                               
};

double bar(double, double);

double (*Foo::my_ptr_fun)(double,double) = &bar;
```

Whatever you would need a static function pointer for anyway.

This is called `initialization`. `instantiation` means something different in C++.